# What is HMC in generative grammar?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, generative-grammar, movement

I'm currently reading a Ph.D. thesis concerning the structure of English adjectives. These generative trees are used to illustrate the structure of the phrase "someone tall". The author states that Picture 185 is illicit since it violates HMC and Picture 186 is the correct one. So what is HMC and why it doesn't allow the N-to-D movement in this situation? I'm confused.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This stands for "Head Movement Constraint". It was introduced by Lisa Travis in her 1984 MIT dissertation [*Parameters and Effects of Word Order Variation*](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/15211), p. 131:

> Head Movement Constraint: An X<sup>0</sup> may only move into the the [sic] Y<sup>0</sup> which properly governs it.

(Note that X<sup>0</sup> is notation for an X head.)

In your (185), *someone* could not move from N to D, because the A head intervenes. For this reason the AP must be taken as an adjunct of the NP, so that the D does properly govern the N.

Comment: I'm not a student of generative grammar, but am wondering why **someone** is regarded as a determiner there and not a pronoun with **tall** an ascription. *Someone could do it.  Someone tall could do it.* Or is it **some** that is the determiner there, with **one** as the pronoun? Does generative grammar split words like **someone** into two constituents?  Some one tall could do it.

Comment: @TimR I don't think the two ("regarded as a determiner ... and not a pronoun") are mutually exclusive. Pronouns are in complementary distribution with e.g. definite articles (\*the they, likewise \*the someone), so they are typically seen as determiners. I am not familiar with the term ascription. It is possible to analyze *someone* as an internally complex head (just as *in front of* can be seen as a single, internally complex prepositional head), but I'm sorry, I don't see how this is related?

Comment: I was just trying to understand the trees and identify the heads.  I take **some** there as the determiner in the DP, with **one** as the N of the NP in the DP, and **tall** to be predicated of **one** not a modifier of **one** : *Some one [who BE] tall*, not *some tall one*.

Comment: @TimR The trees in the question do not give an analysis of the internal make-up of *someone*. They analyze *someone* as the head of the DP. In (185), the DP governs an AP with head *tall*, which governs an NP from which *someone* has been moved. In (186), the DP governs that NP directly, and the AP modifies the NP.

Comment: So  an AP is always assumed to have a slot for an NP complement?

Comment: @TimR no, that’s the example that the author does not use in the end.